# Proving bijectivity after restriction on codomain

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

While I get this intuitively, I'm not sure how to go about solving it...

> Let $X, Y \ne \emptyset$, and let $f:X \to Y$ be bijective. Let $\emptyset \ne A \subseteq X$ and $B := f\restriction_A(A) = \{f(a) : a \in A\}$.

Let $f' : A → B; x \rightarrow f(x)$, i.e., $f' = f\restriction_A$, the codomain $Y$ has shruken to $B$.

Prove that $f'$ is bijective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the following:

In order to prove that $f'$ is bijective, it's sufficient to prove that (i) $f'$ is injective (ii) $f'$ is surjective.

For injectivity of $f'$: suppose $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$ by injectivity of $f$.

For surjectivity of $f'$: let $b\in B$, then by definition of $B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Then $f'(a)=b$.

---

I can think of another method: to point out an inverse of $f'$: since $f$ is bijective, there exists an inverse $g$. To be proven: $g|_B$ is the inverse of $f'$.